# DB Update Query Performance

Tags: sql, date, sql-update, mariadb, where-clause

I have DB Update query, I want to update `offer_end_dt` to a particular date

```
UPDATE offer SET offer_end_dt = '2020-10-30 00:00:00',
                 last_update_user_nm = 'testUser',
                 last_update_tmst = now()
        WHERE offer_end_dt LIKE '2020-05-31%';
```

In above query I have used `LIKE` because I am not sure about the time.

I ran this query on my test db where I have less record but now I want to run this query on Production DB where we have almost Hundred thousand record.

Is there any way to increase performance of this query? Can I use USE INDEX here? How?

I am using MariaDb.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `offer_end` is a `datetime` (which it should be), you should do date comparisons:

```
WHERE offer_end_dt >= '2020-05-31' and offer_end_dt < '2020-06-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `INDEX(offer_end_dt)` and do

```
WHERE offer_end_dt >= '2020-05-31'
  AND offer_end_dt  < '2020-05-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(With this pattern, there is no need to worry about end-of-month or year, nor leap-year.)